# Android app preferences not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have implemented some app preferences for my app. For strings they work great but not for boolean values. E.g.

```
public class MdSharedPrefs {
    public final static String PREFS_NAME = "prefs";

    public static boolean getSSFlag(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        return prefs.getBoolean(context.getString(R.string.pref_key_ss), false);
    }

    public static void setSSFlag(Context context, boolean newValue) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putBoolean(context.getString(R.string.pref_key_ss),
                newValue);
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }

}
```

And this requires

```
<string name="pref_key_ss"></string>
```

in strings.xml. When I remove this line the project wont compile. But when I leave it this boolean pref does not work. When I click it and go back to main screen and then go back to prefs the value is not checked.

However for strings it works fine.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: i am not sure why't u create the static string, i think problem with that..

Comment: <string name="pref_key_ss"></string> ru giving as empty. try with <string name="pref_key_ss">anyname</string>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my application i am using like this it's working fine

declaration

```
 private static final String SUNDAY_ON = "sunday_selected";
```

getting

```
 state = prefs.getBoolean(SUNDAY_ON, false);
```

storing like this

```
 editor.putBoolean(SUNDAY_ON, value);
```